# How can I specify to add item to the database without also adding the foreign key?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, blazor-server-side

I have the following Models:

```
public interface Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class ComponentOwner : Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Component Component { get; set; }
    public AppUser? User { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public AppUser? UpdatedBy { get; set; }
}

public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = "";
    public string LastName { get; set; } = "";
}
```

and the following async Task that saves the item to the database:

```
    private async Task<Item> SaveItem(Item item)
    {
        Item updatedItem = null;
        using var context = _dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext();

        try
        {

            if (item.Id == 0)
            {
                context.Add(item);
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();

            }
```

When I Save a new ComponentOwner, context.Add(Item) adds the item, but also tries to add a new 'AppUser' at the same time. This causes issues because the AppUser is already created.

Is there a way that I can specify to add the ComponentOwner but not the AppUser?

as soon as 'Context.Add(item)' is hit, it wants to add an AppUser as well as the Component. I only want it to add the ComponentOwner however..
[image]

Comment: if not required, can you remove `?` from `AppUser?`

Comment: It's good practice to use Hungarian notation when defining interfaces. Use `IItem` instead of `Item`.

Answer (score 1):

EF Core relies on [tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking) to determine what to do with entities. In this case it seems that `item.User` is not tracked, so EF tries to add it. There are multiple possible solution to this. To name a few:

1. If you are sure that user exists, you can just attach the entity:

   ```cs
   if(item.User is not null) 
      context.Users.Attach(item.User); // or just context.Attach(item.User);
   ```
2. Fetch user from database and assign it to the root entity:

   ```cs
   if (item.User is not null) 
   {
      var user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == item.User.Id); // TODO: handle null
      item.User = user;
   }
   ```
3. Use [`Find`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1.find?view=efcore-7.0):

   > Finds an entity with the given primary key values. If an entity with the given primary key values is being tracked by the context, then it is returned immediately without making a request to the database. Otherwise, a query is made to the database for an entity with the given primary key values and this entity, if found, is attached to the context and returned. If no entity is found, then null is returned.

   ```cs
   if (item.User is not null) 
   {
      var user = context.Users.Find(item.User.Id); // TODO: handle null
      item.User = user;
   }
   ```